# ADF: Show/hide options in af:navigationPane

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I'm using JDeveloper 11.1.1.7.0

I have followed this tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18941_01/tutorials/jdtut_11r2_43/jdtut_11r2_43.html to create a basic and plain left-side menu in my application.

This tutorial shows more advance topics, but I have created a simple left-side menu, with a list.

I haved created an unbounded task flow, drag/drop a wildcard, then the views, then the control flows, ... It works perfect

In the JSF template, in the left-side, I have this code:

```
<af:navigationPane id="pt_np1" hint="list" value="#{supervision_menu}" var="supervisionInfo">
<f:facet name="nodeStamp">
    <af:commandNavigationItem text="#{supervisionInfo.label}" id="pt_cni1"
                            destination="#{supervisionInfo.destination}"
                            action="#{supervisionInfo.doAction}"/>
</f:facet>
```

I need an advanced feature, and I want to show/hide some options, based on a parameter.

I need to execute a view object with this parameter, process the results, so I get the information to know which options could be shown or hidden.

So, my questions are:

- How could I force to execute this check as the first step of this flow?
- In generated menu.xml and in af:commandNavigationItem, there are visible  attribute. Where should I place the condition?

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you mean by this:

> I need to execute a view object with this parameter.

Assuming you mean "execute a QUERY against the VO", then if you used a [ViewCriteria](https://blogs.oracle.com/fadevrel/entry/adf_how_to_4_adding) to create the where clause fragment that gets ANDed to the VO where clause, then you can use ExecWithParams ([here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iMunXSHhpac),[here](http://andrejusb.blogspot.com/2007/05/executewithparams-in-your-oracle-adf.html), [here](http://ecmtechnicalexpertise.wordpress.com/2013/05/31/adf-11g-passing-information-to-bind-variables/))  and drag this method onto the task flow as part of the navigation to the View. Then this will execute prior to entry to the view. Or use you can use Invoke on there Executables of the Binding layer - drag to top of list of executables, but this is no longer the recommended way, being replaced with the previous method.
if you are not using ViewCriteria (why not?) then one suggestion is to expose a method on the AM containing the VO, and pass the parms to this method and have it call the VO, but this is basically what ExecWithParms does. This method, once exposed, could be utilized in the same fashion as I mentioned above. If you can describe more precisely what you are trying to do I can try to be of more help.

Comment: thank you for your ideas, but finally I have to change the approach to get the best solution, with no manual stuff.

Answer (score 1):

As I told to Joe, the final solution requires to change the approach.

I have made an unbounded task flow, then created a menu, then adding ADF Security and finally shown/hidden options, in function of user roles/permissions.

I hope it helps. Thank you

Comment: I should have asked for (or you should have originally provided) your "use case" and I might have been able to give a more appropriate answer. While I did answer the question that was asked, I am pleased you were able to find a declarative way to fulfill the requirements.